Soliton and Goldstone boson
I'm learning Gross-Pitaevskii model. By spontaneous symmetry breaking one obtains Bogoljubov modes, which ensures Landau criterion. So those modes have two features, for one they are Goldstone bosons corresponding to spontaneous symmetry breaking of $U\left(1\right)$ group. At the same time they leads to superfluid.
On the other hand there could be solitonic excitations which also satisfy Laudau criterion at some finite $\left|\mathbf{k}\right|$, somewhere near a local minimum on the spectrum (cf. Two-Fluid Model).
Based on such intuition, I would say there cannot be Goldstone bosons which, at the same time are topological solitons. Or conversely, If I were to consider some sort of geometric phases/Wilson loop, that cannot be a Goldstone excitation. Would you consider such statement in general correct?
What I had in mind is some sort of model with confinement, where thing gets nonperturbative as $|\mathbf{k}|\rightarrow 0$. But I'm not exactly familiar with actual examples in those area.
I hope my definitions in mind are correct, in particular, Goldstone modes correspond to pole structure of propagators at zero momentum.

Is this useful? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/800713/226902

@Quillo still trying to learn, currently I‘m reading this book by Schakel (ˋBoulevard of broken symmetrie‘), I think there could be topological defects which are at the same time Goldstone bosons, but still don‘t see how to incorporate it into this two-fluid model.
